# How to detect Apple AppStore Country Code on different iOS versions?

Tags: ios, skproduct

In our app we need to detect the country of the of the user's app store.

We are doing this with:

On iOS 13+ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorefront/3182435-countrycode
On iOS < 13 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproduct/1506145-pricelocale

I have a few questions about these two properties:

- Are there any situations where the country code returned from these
  two properties would be different?
- Sometimes SKStoreFront.countryCode returns nil, why would that be?
- If SKStoreFront.countryCode returns nil, is it safe to use
  priceLocale as a fallback? Or would this also be nil?

Thank you